# Easy guide on nuxt3 custom types

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxtjs3

I have a vue file in which i want to use custom types:

```
/* 
file: /components/Grid.vue 
*/

<script setup>
// define Section type
interface Section {
  type: string;
  img: string;
  heading: string;
  content: string;
}

const props = defineProps < {
  sections: Section[],
  baseUrl: string
} > ();
const sections = ref(props.sections);
const baseUrl = ref(props.baseUrl);
</script>
```

it throws `ERROR  [@vue/compiler-sfc] Unexpected reserved word 'interface'. (3:0)`    although typescript is enabled.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're forgetting just one thing. You have to include an attribute for typescript!

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
```

The `lang="ts"` attribute is letting Vue know that you are using TypeScript.
Here is a link to the documentation:
https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#usage-in-single-file-components

Comment: Thanks! I'm now stuck with the problem, that I want to outsource these types.

I wrote my interface definitions to .nuxt/nuxt.d.ts like described at https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/typescript, but they are not read correclty. Where do I put my type definitions?

Comment: And when I call `nuxi typecheck`I get this error:

```
ERROR  nuxt.options.buildModules is not iterable                                                        
```

reproduce: https://github.com/ziegenhagel/apollon/tree/bdc3b2e8f78fa4b997f3d9f73967ebb74985e8f4